# When i execute Test Runner class getting error "cannot invoke FindElement() method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p48ZM.png) feature file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enByl.png) Step definition class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo6ZQ.png) Test Runner class

** another feature file but it has background step
Feature: Login to SWAG LAB

Background:
Given Launch the browser and navigage to Swag URl

Scenario: Login to SWAG LAB app with multilpe set of users
When user enter follwoing multiple users crdentials
|uName        |password|
|standard_user|secret_sauce|

Step defifniton file
public class DataTableLoginStep {
WebDriver driver;

```
@When("user enter follwoing multiple users crdentials")
public void dataTableCred(DataTable data) {
    
    List<Map<String,String>> users=data.asMaps(String.class,String.class);// { "firstName": "Thomas", "lastName": "Brown",  "age": "30" }, 
    for(Map<String,String> user:users) {
        String userName=user.get("uName");
        this.driver.findElement(By.id("user-name")).sendKeys(userName);
        
        String password=user.get("password");
        this.driver.findElement(By.id("user-name")).sendKeys(password);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

/** got error like  Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null
at stepDefinitions.DataTableLoginStep.dataTableCred(DataTableLoginStep.java:21)**/

Comment: could anybody help?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

You declare a `driver` attribute in your test class but then create an other  `driver`  in the  `launch_the_browser_and_navigate_to_swag_url` method.
The first `driver` object is accessible anywhere in the class but is initialised to null by default since you don't provide a value. The other driver object, which is declared in a method, is only visible in this specific method.
Thus, when you call your test case, it tries to call the `findElement` method on the unitialised `driver`.
What you need to do is instead of creating a method-scoped object in your  `launch_the_browser_and_navigate_to_swag_url` method, set your class-scoped driver to the same value using the keyword `this`, ie

```java
public void launch_the_browser_and_navigate_to_swag_url(){
this.driver = new WebDriver(options);
//rest of your method
}
```

Also, you used screenshots of your code which makes it hard to read and copy/paste the content. In the future, please try to follow [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when posting.

Comment: Please check i added another feature file and step def class ,for this alos i'm getting same error